# How to restrict filling duplicate entry in Google forms

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-apps

I am working on a Google form where I keep receiving responses every minute. I want to restrict people in case if they are filling the response with the same unique id in column R.
So basically when anyone click on submit button, form should check the values in column R with the value in current form and restrict the user while filling up the form.

I tried doing this in Google form script editor but didn't get the exact code which can validate and stop the user while submitting the form.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sanjay

Comment: not possible. google for similar questions on this forum. scripts do not run at form filling time.

Comment: You would need to create an Apps Script Web App with your own custom input form in order to do what you want.  You could give people pre-filled urls that pre-fill the Form, and then make sure that the option to display a link to submit another response is never shown after the Form is submitted.  But if you are going to supply prefilled URLs, you need to do that by email, or a web page.  And you'll need to construct the prefilled URL in code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that it can implemented in on submit trigger and expecting a script to be implemented on COLUMN R to check the duplication.

Answer (score 1):

As Zig and Sandy mentioned it is not possible with live forms.
However you have the on submit trigger. You can write your script to look for duplicates of the last record when the form is submitted and in case there is any picks up the email (maybe a required field if they don't have to sign in to fill the form) and let them know their duplicated submit has been removed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that it can implemented in on submit trigger and expecting a script to be implemented on COLUMN R to check the duplication.