# How to build a field "username" in Google forms, and make per username one submit

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, add-on

I am trying to make a Google form in which I want a field "username" where users can enters their username and submits the form but when they try to submit again using the same username the form should not be submitted and displays error message "You have already submitted"

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388646/how-to-restrict-filling-duplicate-entry-in-google-forms) what you're trying to do? The short answer is: it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict filling duplicate entry in Google forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388646/how-to-restrict-filling-duplicate-entry-in-google-forms)

Comment: @james-Z try post a quetion on how to filter the form response instead. i will help.

Answer (score 0):

at the moment there is no way to allow restrictions for unique answers per specific questions, however, you can restrict one response per Google Account by going to settings on the form, clicking responses and collecting email responses along with "Limit to one response".